# How to get the merged face attributes at point?

Tags: faces

The appearance of a given character is determined by faces from various sources and `face-remapping-alist`. How to determine the properties Emacs ultimately uses after taking all sources into account? What I'm looking for is an attribute list that could be used for the `default` face, i.e. one specifiying all attributes.

`background-color-at-point` and `foreground-color-at-point` come close for the respective attributes. But they don't take into account `face-remapping-alist`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear to me. But I guess you're asking how to tell what faces actually have a visual effect on a given character.

Not sure this answers the question at all, but:

1. Node [Displaying Faces](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Faces.html) of the Elisp manual says how various faces affect the display of a character they act on.
2. `C-u C-x =` tells you what faces are used on the character after the cursor, from both text properties and overlays.  That uses function `describe-char`, which you can use programmatically.

Hopefully someone else will have a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The library [face-explorer](https://github.com/Lindydancer/face-explorer) contains, among else, functions that untangle all face sources. For example `face-explorer-face-attributes-at` returns the attributes used at a position in the buffer. It take `face-remapping-alist` into account.

This package was originally designed to be used be packages that convert text with face information to other formats. Concretely, it's used in the [e2ansi](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi) package which emits ANSI sequences, to make it possible to display highlighted text in a terminal window.

The package also contains other tools. For example `face-explorer-describe-face` describes a face, including all underlying definitions. (Think of this as a `describe-char` on steroids.)

Or, why not play around with `face-explorer-simulate-display-mode`, a minor mode that simulates how a face (or a theme) would look using, say, a grayscale monitor, or an 8 color terminal.